# Update and retrieve records from Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am a new for Postgres. Currently I hit a situation, I need to retrieve a record from DB/table, then update this record with some changes, then retrieve the updated record again to return to customer, these 3 operations are executed sequentially.

After I run the above 3 steps, sometimes it seems  the record has not been updated. But in fact the record has been updated, I suspect when I retrieve the record, Postgres return a cached data rather than fresh data. Actually all DB operations are correct, I guess just Postgres returns cached records.

I am wondering if there is any mechanism to flush my updated data immediately?

Another question is, I am wondering which one is a good practice:

- Update a record (actually write to DB), then immediately retrieve the record from DB, both operations are using statement to operate.
- Update a record (actually write to DB), then don't retrieve record from DB, because we know updated data, we just use these data to return to customer. However, the record might fail to write DB.

Any ideas for the above?

Comment: Please show us your code. Are you using transactions?

Comment: "*don't retrieve record from DB, because we know updated data. However, the record might fail to write DB.*" - uh, if it failed to write you would have gotten an error from the database.

Comment: Why don't you use RETURNING in your UPDATE statement? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dml-returning.html

Comment: Use `UPDATE ... RETURNING`

Comment: The problem is in your client, but you haven't told us what that is.

Answer (score 0):

Some programming languages do db calls asynchronously, meaning that your code is moving on to the next db operation without waiting for the first to finish. So, it could be as simple as using your language's "await" keyword to make sure you are waiting for your db to finish the "update record" before trying to read it again.

If you are writing raw sql or you know it is not an issue with making several db call asynchronously, you could try writing your update and read calls as a single **transaction**.

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/tutorial-transactions.html if you're unfamiliar with writing transactions.

Comment: PostgreSQL version 8.3, are you really using this outdated manual? Februari 2008, that is 14 years ago...

Comment: whoops didn't notice since it was the same syntax. Ty